# Facing SoapFaultClientException while consuming SOAP Web Service in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap-client

On changing package-info.java file generated by this plugin in spring boot

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <generatePackage>com.example.demo.schemas.eligibility.test</generatePackage>
                <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>*.wsdl</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

I'm receiving this Exception that giving sense that we can't change package-info.java file for SOAP Xml classes.

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: BIP3113E: Exception detected in message flow gen.CRMEligibilityGS.SOAP Input (broker PTCLDEVBK01) 
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:830) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:624) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:378) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.example.demo.config.SOAPConnector.callWebService(SOAPConnector.java:8) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.client.SoapClient.getCustmoerEligibilityResponse(SoapClient.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.EligibilityRestController.getCountryDetails(EligibilityRestController.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

So can we make change in package-info.java file generated by plugin jaxb2 while generating java classes from wsdl file?
Or this exception is telling something else?

this is my package-info.java file

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://CRMEligibilityGS")
package com.example.demo.schemas.eligibility.test;
```

Using Java 8 with Spring Boot 2.1.4.RELEASE

Client Class Code

```
 public CRMEligibilityGSResponse getCustmoerEligibilityResponse(CRMEligibilityGS eligibilityRequest) {
        webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate(jaxMarshaller);
        CRMEligibilityGSResponse response = (CRMEligibilityGSResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive("http://abcxyz?wsdl", eligibilityRequest);    // url is sample actual one is different that also ends with ?wsdl and url is private
        System.out.println("Response is :"+ response);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: The error is telling you something else. You get an error from the server.

Comment: From the Requested Server?

Comment: This line `WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:624`  (when you look at the sources) is only called when handling a response. So yes you get an error from the server. Maybe your request isn't correct (missing fields, or something else, so check the server). The erorr message contains an error code **BIP3113E** maybe that is helpful?

Comment: But could be related to you changing things on your side, making the request invalid. What isn't clear to me is did you change the generated code? If so why? You generally shouldn't be doing things like that.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I've double check again not missing anything on my side in request body. Isn't this the issue if I change something in package-info.java file so, the request will not be correctly parsed and sent to server
I was trying to replace
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://CRMEligibilityGS") with this
 @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://CRMEligibilityGS", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
to avoid this exception 
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element
otherwise face this always.

Comment: Any other way we can stop this exception? 
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"CRMEligibilityGS"). Expected elements are <{http://CRMEligibilityGS}CRMEligibilityGS>,<{http://CRMEligibilityGS}CRMEligibilityGSResponse>
I didn't have any? do you @M.Deinum

Comment: Modifying the generated code isn't the answer. You should fix the actual problem, which you now moved to the server because you are now producing the wrong XML (due to your change).

Comment: I do have access to wsdl file should I change something there?

Comment: No. You should change something in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Deinum, 
In code it's simple a web template that is calling soap web service like this 

        CRMEligibilityGSResponse response = (CRMEligibilityGSResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive("http://xyz?wsdl", eligibilityRequest);

so, any hind what can we change to avoid this javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"CRMEligibilityGS"). Expected elements are <{CRMEligibilityGS}CRMEligibilityGS>,<{CRMEligibilityGS}CRMEligibilityGSResponse>

Comment: Please don't add code as comments, that is plain unreadable. Instead edit your question to provide additional information. Is the request class itself annotated with `@XmlRootElement` or just `@XmlElement`? I would also suggest a newer version of the maven plugin 0.14.1 (the most recent one). Also why are you calling the URL with `?wsdl`? You shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Request class is annotated with `@XmlRootElement(name = "CRMEligibilityGS")`

Comment: Also why are you calling the URL with ?wsdl? You shouldn't be doing that? As that will return the wsdl NOT issue the request.

Comment: actual url is also having ?wsdl and I'm able to access wsdl with the url for example `http://xyz?wsdl` on any browser.

Comment: That is weird, as that is generally the trigger to retrieve the wsdl. I would at least try it without the WSDL. But as requested, please add the calling code to your question and the resulting error (the full stacktrace please!).

Comment: Sorry, I've updated question only actual url is not there because it's private one.